# How to download files from Coursera online courses using any grabber or any other online method?

Tags: bulk-download, coursera

I have registered for one of the online courses on `coursera.org`. When the course is completed there will be around 60 or more .pdf slides and corresponding video lectures. I tried downloading using Internet Download Manager grabber but it failed.

What is the most efficient way to download the .pdfs etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ["Down Them All" extension available for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/). I use it too - saves a lot of time.

Comment: Let me try it. Thank you. Is there any similar thing for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Once a course has finished you may still be able to review all the videos and slides, depending on the course.

There is a [Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coursera-dl) for downloading resources from Coursera.

Comment: Thanks , let me check it. But I haven't installed python in my system. Can I use this package or similar with an executable type file.